# How can we integrate Big Commerce with Very Good Security (VGS)

Tags: bigcommerce

Do we add a VGS input on the checkout page and then manually handle the payment using the Payments API exposed by Big Commerce?

Comment: The payments API is only compatible with certain providers, I don’t think VGS is one of them. I Think you’ll need to build a custom checkout customization with the checkout-sdk,  follow the steps here for VGS integration: https://www.verygoodsecurity.com/docs/guides/payments , and you may need to build your own server to manually create orders with the BC orders API, process payments separately, and update the order statuses when those payments are processed. All in all - not an easy task. You may even need a database to contain this information

Comment: Something like Server-to-Server checkouts might apply here too? https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-checkout-api

Comment: Yes, but if you’re using that, I think you’ll still need to build out a front-end to facilitate the checkout process. @dazza5000 - you’ll still need a way to collect the shipping address, billing address, etc - the server-to-server checkout seems to be for building an entirely separate checkout flow on a headless site - you’d probably want to hook into the existing checkout service & front end components provided by BigCommerce, but just take over processing the order & payment separately. https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js-example Is an example repo with a React implementation.

Comment: There are a few ways to go, really - you can try to inject a script into the existing checkout page (Optimized One Page Checkout) - you’ll have to fight against a lot of tricky things and override certain events and use mutation listeners, as you have no control of the embedded Checkout App that BC uses (its an embedded react app, source code not available). Alternatively, you can use the repo I linked as a starting point to developing your own checkout with full control - there are help articles in the BC docs. Third option is building your own front end from scratch with checkout-SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't implement a full solution, but using VGS collect (https://www.verygoodsecurity.com/docs/vgs-collect/js/overview) and building out a custom checkout using the checkout sdk and the repository below as a reference you can achieve the desired outcome.

https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js-example